# 2009 ford focus,will not start

Tags: starting

I have a 2009 ford focus,replaced battery.cleaned cables and posts,car will not even turn over. one min.its fine next min the car is dead. I don't know what to check for now.

Comment: What do you mean by "dead"? no lights, no nothing? or lights but no starter? I would check the bonding between battery / engine or battery / chassis...

Comment: Solar Mike, After replacing the battery the car started once, I shut it off and tried again, it would not even turn over.the head lights were bright,every thing came on as it should with a new battery.

Comment: So, did you check the bonding?

Comment: Solar Mike, Bonding was good, after making several calls I was told that it sounds like a bad Ignition switch, ! replaced the switch. car starts up every time, no more problems. Thanks Solar Mike for your help.